# Unable to inject a property into log4j2.xml from application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, logback

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNoWi.png)I created a bundle **test.properties** with a property **contextName=demo-app**, and in the log4j2.xml I put `<property name="contextName">${bundle:test:contextName}</property>`. I have used this property for the log files name. Instead of getting **demo-app** as the filename, I'm getting **contextName_IS_UNDEFINED**. Why?

I created the test.properties inside resources folder. Still facing the problem with property injection.

[Invalid Filename Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNoWi.png)

Comment: Are you really getting the string "contextName_IS_UNDEFINED"? When lookups fail to resolve you usually get `${bundle:test:contextName}`.

Comment: I've actually created a logging library using logback where I have this log4j.xml file. I'm using this library in another spring-boot application to be used for logging. But, getting above issue with the filename.

Comment: And what is the relation between your Logback-based library and Log4j 2.x?

Comment: I'm not using log4j2 dependency. Just logback-classic. So, there's no relation